# Directional Derivative (3 variables)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, partial-derivative

Find the derivative of the function $ u = xy + yz + zx$ at the point $M(2,1,3) $ in the direction from this point to the point $N(5,5,15)$

When it is 2 variables, I can easly find a vector that pass through the given points and is a unit vector. But how should I procedure in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

P.S: i've added the tag linear algebra since I think my problem is not, directly, the calculus.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to compute directional derivative using $\nabla_vu=\nabla u\cdot v$? where $v$ is unit vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the relative vector between the points, you merely subtract the coordinates of $M$ from the coordinates of $N$.

$$N-M = (5,5,15) - (2,1,3) = (3, 4, 12)$$

This vector is not unit, but if you divide this vector by its magnitude, you will have a unit vector.  Do you know how to find the magnitude of a vector?

Comment: magnitude is the same as the euclidean norm?

Comment: Yes, the terminology is equivalent here.

Answer (score 2):

Directional derivative can be calculated as follows, assumed $F$ differentiable at $p_0$

$$D_{\vec u}F(p_0)=\nabla F(p_0).\vec u$$
where $$\vec u=\frac{(5-2,5-1,15-3)}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2+12^2}}=\frac{(3,4,12)}{13}$$ is direction 
vector and $p_0=M$
$$\nabla F=(y+z,x+z,y+x)\Rightarrow \nabla F(p_0)=(1+3,2+3,2+1)=(4,5,3)$$
$$=\nabla F(p_0).\vec u=4.\frac3{13}+5.\frac4{13}+3.\frac{12}{13}=\frac{68}{13}$$